# Height and width not being respected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-awesome

When I set the height and width of the popupform, the values are not taken into account.

```
<button type="button" class="awe-btn" onclick="@(Url.Awe().PopupFormAction().Url(Url.Action("create")).Success("createQuestionset").Height(800).Width(800))">@Mui.Create qs</button>
```

No matter what values i set, the size of the popup remains the same.

Is there anything more to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code you show should work providing that everything else is corect

for example if I put this line:

```
<button type="button" class="awe-btn" onclick="<%:Url.Awe().PopupFormAction().Url(Url.Action("create", "SimpleMeals")).Height(800).Width(800)%>">Create</button>
```

in the [**demo app**](https://awesome.codeplex.com/releases/view/121694) PopupFormDemo/Index.aspx it works and the popup will have the desired size

my guess is that some js files are modified/corrupted or a buggy jqueryUI version or some other js is overriding the default behaviour of jquery ui dialog

Comment: @vishalk you should click the V under the upvote/downvote if this is the accepted answer